# How to troubleshoot IIS Queued/Hung Requests on .NET App

Tags: iis, request, freeze

Our team are spinning our wheels on an issue we are seeing in IIS. We are using New Relic (monitoring/reporting) and Stackify (logging) on our servers. We use NetScaler as our load balancer From the New Relic perspective it appears as if the throughput to the server drops from 500-600 request per minute to 5-10 request per minute. While looking at IIS directly on the affected server it appears that requests are queueing and are becoming hung.

We have looked at the event logs, access logs, and process dumps (which tells us that things are hung). Developers are combing through the code but for the past two weeks, that has caused them to jump from theory to theory with no tangible conclusions that lead to a fix.

What other things can we do to debug this behavior on the servers?

Comment: Dump analysis requires experience, so not surprised to see even developers with source code cannot draw a clear conclusion. Hire some experienced consultants, or simply open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to ask Microsoft.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue ? We are facing this as well.

Comment: We did find the problem. It turned out to be a lightInject misconfiguration. We did some brut force testing and overserved the call stack to find the issue.